# About "performing" in BEAM "planCalcScore", an extention on MatSim

Tags: java, scala

I'm interested in the traffic simulator BEAM, an extention on MatSim.

In the sample scenario "sf-light", I changed the "performing" in " planCalcScore " in “matsim.conf” from 6.0 to 60.0, but the value in “scorestats.txt” was unchanged .

original"matsim.conf"

```
planCalcScore {
  writeExperiencedPlans = true
  learningRate = "1.0"
  BrainExpBeta= "2.0"
  lateArrival= "-18"
  earlyDeparture = "-0"
  performing = "6.0"
  traveling="-6.0"
  waiting="-0"
}
```

This is my "matsim.conf"

```
planCalcScore {
  writeExperiencedPlans = true
  learningRate = "1.0"
  BrainExpBeta= "2.0"
  lateArrival= "-18"
  earlyDeparture = "-0"
  performing = "60.0"
  traveling="-6.0"
  waiting="-0"
}
```

Is the BEAM "performing" configuration different from the MATSIM configuration?

Thanks a lot in advance.